Get the pose information of objects for picking and placing
I'm performing a task, using a camera realsense D435 to observe a given object at any time. Next, the camera sends data about the object's position to the robot arm that picks up and drops the object.
I got pointclouds data via the realsense library and visualized it. I do not, however, know how to get the object's pose to send to robot arm.
I used multi-scale icp in open3d to remove a part of noise in pointclouds.
How can I get the object's pose to send to the robot arm?

if you have a GPU you may try this https://github.com/NVlabs/Deep_Object_Pose it only need 2d image no need pointclouds
